# Algolia transliteration Cyrillic strings

Tags: algolia

Does anyone have experience with Algolia & transliteration? For example indexes contain Cyrillic text but user is typing in latin letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, most search engines don't support transliteration natively; same for Algolia.

The best way to handle such a use-case is to enrich your objects with the transliterated attributes before sending them to the search engine.

Maybe you can try [gausby/translitit-cyrillic-russian-to-latin](https://github.com/gausby/translitit-cyrillic-russian-to-latin)?

Comment: Transliteration is an option I can maybe add title_tr body_tr and add them as searchable but not in output that might be actually very good solution so I do not care what user type in search it shows results even if he type latin characters

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one little clarification. Let's say we have one field like name and many name translations

you can form object like

```
{ 

     name: 'whatever',
     translations: {
          ru: 'без разницы',
          he: 'οτιδήποτε',
          de: 'was auch immer'
    }
}
```

Then you put in your searchable attributes name, translations.ru, translations.he, translations.de so search will return 'whatever' when user type in 'без ра' for example.